# Problems creating Google account for domain

Tags: google-account

I purchased a domain name, and it looks like it was previously used by someone else. When I try to create a Google account with my own email address info@mydomain.com, Google tells me it is already taken. So I try to recover it. I must do either one of the following steps:
1. Logon with a known device
2. Logon with a known password
3. Send an SMS to a mobile number which is registered by the previous owner.

Since it is my domain, which I purchased, I have access to all my emails for that domain, but still Google don't allow me to take over this email address into a new account.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a programming question. This isn't Google support.

Comment: You may have bought the domain from a registrar, but google may still have an old account in their system, from the previous owner. You will have to contact Google, but there may not be a way to fix this. In other words, you may own the domain, but you can't use Google to manage it. The only ones that can tell you the right answer, however, is Google support. And besides, this question is off topic here on Stack Overflow because it is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

Google might be saying that either:

- The Google domain name that you are trying to use has been taken by someone else
- Your domain has been stolen or hacked
- You must recover your account

You are assuming that the third one must be true, and that might not be the case.

Also, you must login with an account that is part of your domain. If the email you used is not in the domain, you must login into a domain email.